# Integrating A 3rd-Party Custom Payment Gateway with Shopify

Tags: shopify, payment-gateway, shopify-app

I'm looking to integrate my app as a 3rd party payment provider for Shopify merchants to add to their websites. This will allow customers to select my app as a payment option, and upon purchase will be re-directed to a web-page hosted on my app, where they can complete their purchase. After completing their purchase they would then be re-directed back to the merchant's Shopify website.

I've read a lot of the docs online about how to do this but I still have some uncertainty around some things:

1. I've already seen that this was done by using a Hosted Payments SDK,
   but has since been deprecated. The docs mention to create an app in
   the Partner Dashboard or Shopify CLI, as well as create a payment
   extension. From my understanding the only thing I would need would
   be the payment extension? I would just like to be able to send the
   payment request from the merchant's Shopify website to my app
   (likely through a webhook) which can then process it and return a
   link to redirect the customer to the necessary page to make the
   payment.
2. I'm struggling to find any online documentation or examples
   on how you would create this payment extension.
3. I also can't find
   any examples on how I would set up a 3rd party payment gateway by
   creating a Shopify Payment app.

I'm hoping someone can assist me with this. Thanks!